# A characterization of semiartinian modules

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, modules

Recall that a right module $M_R$ is called **semiartinian** if every nonzero homomorphic image has nonzero socle. It's well known that the following two statements are equivalent:

1. $M$ is semiartinian.
2. Every nonzero homomorphic image of $M$ has essential socle.

It's clear that $(2)$ implies (1). But how can I prove the converse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Argue by contradiction.
 Assume that $M$ is semiartinian and that $N$ is a nonzero homomorphic image of $M$ whose socle $A_0$ is not essential. There will exist a nonzero submodule $B\leq N$ that is disjoint from $A_0$. Enlarge the submodule $A_0$ to a submodule $A_1$ that is maximal for the condition $A_1\cap B = 0$. The module $N/A_1$ is nonzero, since
$$0\neq B\cong B/(A_1\cap B)\cong (A_1+B)/A_1\leq N/A_1.$$
$N/A_1$ is a quotient of $N$, which is isomorphic to a quotient of $M$, so $N/A_1$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $M$. Since $M$ is semiartinian, the nonzero quotient $N/A_1$ must have a nonzero simple submodule. This means that $N$ has a submodule $A_2$ covering $A_1$ (i.e., $A_1\lneq A_2$, and there is no intermediate submodule $A_1\lneq C\lneq A_2$). By the maximality condition on $A_1$ we have $A_2\cap B\neq 0$ and by the modularity $\textrm{Sub}(N)$  (= the submodule lattice of $N$) we even get that  $S:=A_2\cap B$ covers $0$. Hence $S$ is a simple submodule of $N$ contained in $B$. All simple submodules of $N$ are contained in the socle $A_0$ which is contained in $A_1$. We get that $S\subseteq A_1\cap B=0$. This is a contradiction, since $S\neq 0$.

Comment: How is $N/A_1$ isomorphic to a quotient of $M$ ?. Also, what does Sub(N) stand for?. The argument of the proof is not so clear.

Comment: @HusseinEid: $N/A_1$ is a quotient of $N$, which is itself isomorphic to a quotient of $M$. A quotient of a quotient is isomorphic to a quotient, according to the 3rd Isomorphism Theorem. $\textrm{Sub}(M)$ denotes the submodule lattice of $N$. (I will add this to the answer.)

Comment: Thanks @Keith for your help.